# Confused about the notation for rule C.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This is from "Introduction to Mathmatical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , forth edition , chapter 2.6 [Rule C]

In the book , The "rule C" deduction in a first-order theory K is shown with the notation  $\Gamma \vdash_C \mathscr B$. The confusion for me is that in $\Gamma \vdash_K \mathscr B$ , K is said to be a first order theory , so that would mean that in $\Gamma \vdash_C \mathscr B$ , C is a first order theory , but that seems to be not true. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Rule C is a **new** rule. The gist of **Prop.2.10** (page 80) is that adding the rule to the predicate calculus (Axioms+MP+Gen) what we get is a *conservative extension*: if $\Gamma \vdash_C \mathscr B$, then $\Gamma \vdash \mathscr B$

Comment: Can "rule C" be thought of as a rule of inference (like MP or Gen)?

Comment: Yes, similar to the Deduction Theorem; having $\Gamma,A \vdash B$ the theorem asserts that we can build a derivation $\Gamma \vdash A \to B$. It is a meta-theory that we can use in a derivation without the necessity of effectively producing the "native" derivation.

Comment: See also the post [Rule C](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56218/rule-c-introduction-to-mathematical-logic-by-mendelson-fifth-edition)